# Django unapply migration

Tags: python, django, migration

I have a custom made migration:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [('blah', 'my_previous_migration'),]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            sql=[("SQL HERE")],
            reverse_sql=[("SQL UNDO HERE")])
    ]
```

This migration is already applied. I want to create a migration to undo that migration, basically following what the docs say: [unapply migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/migration-operations/#runsql)

But I can't find any reference on how to unapply a migration or have a migration run the `reverse_sql` portion of the migration.

Comment: is the migration snippet applied locally or have you already shared this with public/project or set on production?

Comment: it's already on prod, that is why I need a migration to undo this one.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the snippet `accident` and the additional one `fix`.

When writing custom SQL migrations you should usually provide the reverse part otherwise you can not roll it back to prior state without loosing the integrity of your schema and/or data.

`accident` should provide sql to revert itself. The `fix` that rolls `accident` back should therefor consist of both operations interchanged.

You might want to read [about squashing migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing) afterwards.

EDIT: the term operations might by confusing as it is part of the migration system :) - will say: interchange `sql` and `reverse_sql` in `fix` migration